# How to visualize data while debugging?

Tags: java, debugging, data-visualization, debuggervisualizer

I need to check some visual aspects of my application, say, that some shape is correct. Eclipse does not have an ability to watch other than `toString()`. So, I need to go back to old good debug hooks. So, I wrote a standalone class, which displays objects of given type, but I still can't use it. If I put it in code, then it freezes when breakpoint.

Is it possible to pass objects somewhere into separate classloader or JVM or something, so that I can inspect it interactively?

Comment: There are not really many details provided so far. I assume that by "objects" you mean something like a `Shape`, that can be drawn to a `Graphics`. Indeed, this will become tricky. Of course you can pragmatically create a debugging window that you can call from anywhere using a call like `DebugWindow.show(theShapes)` or so. But once you have a breakpoint in the Event-Dispatch-Thread, this will not work any more. The only idea I have so far would be some sort of second JVM and a local socket connection where the data items are transferred via serialization, but I don't know an library for that